For an R ggplot chart, how would I have the legend label be the value of a variable?
the below code makes a chart. There are blue bars with a grey line on top. Currently the legend says "Current Month" for the bar, but instead I want to use the value of a variable called reportYM1. I tried putting in reportYM1 without the quotes, but it showed up as reportYM1, not the value of the variable. The color of the bars turned to grey instead of blue as well for some reason.
What am I missing?
    library(knitr)
library(markdown)
library(rmarkdown)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)
library(kableExtra)
library(shadowtext)
library(ggplot2)
library(RODBC)
library(lubridate)
library(formattable)
library(scales)

reportMonth = "2024-05-01"
reportMonth <- as.character(reportMonth[1,1])   
reportYM1 = format(date(reportMonth), "%b %Y")

combinedDataA <- data.frame(category.x=c('HM_Admit_1_Percentage','HM_Admit_1_Percentage','HM_Admit_1_Percentage'),
                             valueP=c(0,0.0667,0.9333),
                             label=c('99221','99222','99223'),
                             category.y=c('HM_ytdAdmit_1_Percentage','HM_ytdAdmit_1_Percentage','HM_ytdAdmit_1_Percentage'),
                             valueH=c(0,0.1162791,0.8837209))


# Plotting
ggplot(data = combinedDataA, aes(x = label)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = valueP * 100, fill = "Current Month"), stat = "identity") +
  geom_line(aes(y = valueH * 100, group = 1, color = "YTD"), size = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(y = valueH * 100, color = "YTD"), size = 3) +
  geom_shadowtext(aes(y = 0, label = scales::percent(valueP)), vjust = -0.5, color = "white", size = 3.5, bg.colour = "black", bg.r = 0.2) +  # White text at the bottom of the bar
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1), 
    limits = c(0, 110), 
    expand = c(0, 0)  
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Current Month" = "#0060a9"), guide = guide_legend(title = NULL)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("YTD" = "#bdbdb1"), guide = guide_legend(title = NULL)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, title = NULL, subtitle = NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y.right = element_blank())  


If Current Month and YTD are columns in your data frame, take them out of double quotes.  (Though you'll need to enclose Current Month in backticks.)  The colour of the fill changed because you define the colour on the basis of the character constant "Current Month", not the column Current Month.  I'm guessing that the column Current Month does not contain the value "Current Month"...  If you need more help, please provide a minimal reproducible example.

I edited the code to interpedently make the chart.  Current Month and YTD aren't column names, they're just something I added after the fact.
In my example code, reportYM1 currently is "May 2024" and I want that to be the legend label for the blue bar rather than "Current Month".  The idea is that each month that label would change.

Thanks, I was able to achieve what I wanted by using the below code.  I changed the values of all rows in the category.x column to the variable and used dataframe$columnname to assign that to the fill.  Also, in scale_fill_manual I don't need to specify the label name for the color to work.
    combinedDataA <- data.frame(category.x=c('HM_Admit_1_Percentage','HM_Admit_1_Percentage','HM_Admit_1_Percentage'),
                             valueP=c(0,0.0667,0.9333),
                             label=c('99221','99222','99223'),
                             category.y=c('HM_ytdAdmit_1_Percentage','HM_ytdAdmit_1_Percentage','HM_ytdAdmit_1_Percentage'),
                             valueH=c(0,0.1162791,0.8837209))

combinedDataA$category.x <- reportYM1


ggplot(data = combinedDataA, aes(x = label)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = valueP * 100, fill = combinedDataA$category.x), stat = "identity") +
  geom_line(aes(y = valueH * 100, group = 1, color = "YTD"), size = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(y = valueH * 100, color = "YTD"), size = 3) +
  geom_shadowtext(aes(y = 0, label = scales::percent(valueP)), vjust = -0.5, color = "white", size = 3.5, bg.colour = "black", bg.r = 0.2) +  # White text at the bottom of the bar
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1), 
    limits = c(0, 110), 
    expand = c(0, 0)  
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#0060a9"), guide = guide_legend(title = NULL)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("YTD" = "#bdbdb1"), guide = guide_legend(title = NULL)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, title = NULL, subtitle = NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y.right = element_blank())  


I don't have the shadowtext package and I believe it's irrelevant to your question, so I don't intend to install it.  Here is a MRE based on the mtcars dataset that allows you to use the value of one of the columns in the data frame to define your fill label.  However, this is not an efficient way to do things and I would not recommend it.  Instead, I would either write a custom function to allow you to specify the legend name, or provide a (one row) control dataset to do the same thing.
mtcars1 <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(
    my_label = "A custom label"
  ) 

mtcars1 %>% 
  ggplot() +
    geom_bar(aes(y = cyl, fill = as.factor(gear))) +
    scale_fill_discrete(name = mtcars1$my_label)



Thanks, seeing mtcars1$my_label was a good reminder that I can reference a value in a data frame like that.
